# how to assign vue value to vue data variable to Vue.nexttick function?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

```
export default {
    name: "AddNewAddressComponent",

    data() {
        return {
            addressdata: {
                address: '',
                selected_city: '',
                selected_state: '',
                is_primary: '',

            },
            states: '',
            cities: '',
            // errors: null,

            lat: '',
            lng: '',
            submitted: false,

        }
    },



//Next Tick func,its in mounted


this.$nextTick(function () {

    $("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function (event, latLng) {

        $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
        $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());

        this.lat = $("#lat").val();
        this.lng = $("#lng").val();
        console.log("here" + this.lat + "lng:" + this.lng);
        $("#reset").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you're experiencing a javascript scoping issue. try the following:

```
export default {

    /* ... */

    mounted(){

        let _this = this; // <---- keep Vue model in a variable.

        $("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function (event, latLng) {

            // we're now inside an inner scope,
            // 'this' isn't Vue model anymore,
            // which is why we prepared '_this'.

            $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
            $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());

            _this.lat = $("#lat").val();
            _this.lng = $("#lng").val();
            console.log("here" + _this.lat + "lng:" + _this.lng);
            $("#reset").show();
        });
    },

    /* ... */

}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: You can use `arrow` too

Comment: Thanks for helping,i tried both methods(arrow function and also with _this approach ),but its not working.these variables no accessible in vue data variable.for now i am using direct approach for sending data ,which  is not long lasting.i want proper solution.By which i can assign javascipt data to vue data varialbles

Comment: //for now em sending data directly through vue form data,                                                                                         
                        formData.append('lat', $("#lat").val());
                        formData.append('lng', $("#lng").val());

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as [geevee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339235/how-to-assign-vue-value-to-vue-data-variable-to-vue-nexttick-function/57340465#57340465) explained, and besides using a variable to store the Vue this, you can also use arrow functions as [Satyam Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339235/how-to-assign-vue-value-to-vue-data-variable-to-vue-nexttick-function#comment101169282_57340465) metioned:

```
mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Use arrow functions in the callback
    $('#geocomplete').on('geocode:dragged', (event, latLng) => {
      $('input[name=lat]').val(latLng.lat());
      $('input[name=lng]').val(latLng.lng());
      this.lat = $('#lat').val();
      this.lng = $('#lng').val();
      console.log('here lat: ' + this.lat + ' lng: ' + this.lng);
      $("#reset").show();
    })
  });
}
```

[Explanation and examples of arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)

> "*An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.*"

A simulated sample can be referred on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoMBKJ?editors=1011)